# Latest Git - No SSH option on install

Tags: git, windows-7, ssh

I installed 1.7.0.2 on Windows 7 and didn't see an option to choose the Git's ssh or Plink for the secure client.  How do I set this?  Does the environment variable GIT_SSH still work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange, for I don't see [any ticket opened on that topic on msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/list).

And here what I saw during the installation:

[alt text http://img52.imageshack.us/img52/6313/gitsetupssh.png](http://img52.imageshack.us/img52/6313/gitsetupssh.png)

May be no  Plink was detected on your computer, meaning that, in that case, this screen was bypassed?

Comment: Oy vey. That may be it, I didn't have the Putty suite installed yet.  Thanks.

Comment: I stand corrected.  I uninstalled Git and I have the PuTTY suite installed and reinstalled Git did not get the above screen.  I'm not logged in as admin, but run the Git install exe as admin.  I don't have TortoiseGit installed though - I want to use Git Extensions instead.  My ultimate goal is to get a Git server running on my Win 7 box.  Anyways, let me set GIT_SSH manually and see what happens.

Comment: @Steve: well may be that screen is only displayed if you have a Putty.exe installed in the *usual* places? (i.e. `c:\Program files\...`, either for putty suite or for Tortoise Putty)

Comment: @VonC - My copy of putty is in program files\putty.  I tried installing previous versions of msysgit.  1.6.5 didn't give me this screen but 1.6.4 did.  Either way, I can't get git clone to work with ssh - keep getting "can't find repository", I was able to clone w/o ssh.

Comment: @Steve: interesting: are you on W7 32 or 64bit?

Comment: @VonC - 64bit.  I finally got the git clone to work with ssh so it looks like I can do remote!  Turned out to be a path issue.  I cannot tell you how much time I burned on this.  It is not obvious.  Anyways, let me uninstall and try the newest version and see if it works.  If there's no ssh executable screen and it works, then I'm not too concerned although it should be noted.  For the clone, I did not use Tortoise or Git Extensions - I used the command line.

Comment: 1.7.0.2 is definitely buggy.  I cannot push origin master.  Keep getting not a git command.  I'll stick with 1.6.4 for now.  This setup process is making me think of Mercurial.

Comment: @Steve: "This setup process is making me think of Mercurial.": Ouch, that does not sound like a compliment ;) Did you open an issue at http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/list ?

Comment: Looks like this didn't inhibit me from getting git to work, so although it didn't show up, setting the path yourself seems to do the trick.